# Bacon Cipher Decryption

Tags: python, encryption

The Bacon cipher is a very nice cipher which maps the letters `A-Z` to numbers from `0-25` in 5-bit representation (e.g. `A = 00000`, `Z=11001` etc.). A good description is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bacon%27s_cipher).

As part of this, I want to decrypt the following [text](https://www.sie.ro/rcd2017/RCD%20Challenge/1.pdf) which was encrypted with Bacon Cipher. Basically, if it is an upper letter I consider a bit `1` for it and `0` if it is a lower one. Then by splitting in 5-bit groups we get the decryption of the ciphertext. For example the first 5 letters `CrYPt` transforms into `10110` which transforms into `W`.

I inserted the text in a `file.txt`:

```
CrYPtogRapHY iS a ScIEnce Of "seCrET wriTinG". FOr aT Least Two
THoUsAnd yeaRS ThErE haVE bEeN peOPlE WHo WAnTeD to
SEnd MESsaGes WHiCh coUlD oNLY bEeN reAd bY tHe pEOplE FOR
WhOm thEy were INtEndeD. a lOT oF different MEtHODs For
CONceaLiNG MESSAgeS weRE InvENted startINg WiTh ancient
cIPhERS lIke "skYtAle" AnD "AtbasH" AND EndINg WITh mOdERn
SYMmetRIc And puBLiC key eNCryptiON algOriThMS SuCH AS aES
AnD rSa. THe deVelOPMeNt oF CRyPTOgrAPhY coNtiNUeS aND
neveR SToPs! DecRYpT the MessAGe ThAt iS hIDDeN iN tHE TeXt of
This Task! thE alPhaBeT For thE mESsagE cOnsIsTS of alL TWENty
SIx ENGliSh letTErs fROM "a" tO "Z" and sIx puNCtUAtiON MARkS "
", ".", ",", "!", "?", "'"
```

Here is my python code:

```
import re

tr = {26: ' ', 27: '.', 28: ',', 29: '!', 30: '?', 31: '\''}


def transform(binary_ch):
    v = int(binary_ch, 2)
    if v < 26:
        return chr(65 + v)
    return tr[v]


# read the ciphertext from file
crypto_text = open("file.txt").read()

# remove the unnecessary characters (e.g. punctuation marks)
crypto_text = ''.join(ch for ch in crypto_text if ch.isalpha())

# convert to 1 the upper letter and to 0 the lower letter
crypto_text = ''.join('1' if ch.isupper() else '0' for ch in crypto_text)

# split in blocks of 5 characters
crypto_text = re.findall('.'*5, crypto_text)

plain_text = ''.join(transform(ch) for ch in crypto_text)

print crypto_text
print plain_text
```

But the plain is not the expected one. I get this:

`WE[WELCOME[QOU[TO[THE[FOUSTH[EDITIAN[OFSOMANIAN[CSYPTOLOGQ[DAYS^^[WE^HONE[YOU[ENJOV[EIESYLCSYPTOIMOMENT^`

And I think it should be something like:

`We welcome you to the fourth edition of romanian cryptology days etc..`

Also, I am not sure that it is intended to be more readable than this, but also I am considering that I've made a mistake somewhere in the code. Also it could be considered a capture the flag stuff.

Did I make any mistake in the code ?

**Edit:**

If the ciphertext is wrong, the the correct version would be

```
CrYPtogRapHY iS a ScIEnce Of "seCrET wriTinG". FOr aT Least Two
THoUsANd yeaRS ThErE haVE bEeN peOPlE WHo WAnTeD to
SEnd MESsaGes WHiCh coUlD oNLY bEeN reAd by THe pEOplE FOR
WhOm thEy were INtEndeD. a lOT oF diffEREnt MEtHODs For
CONceaLiNG MeSsAges WeRE InvENted startINg WiTh ancient
cIPhERS lIke "skYtAle" aND "AtbasH" AND EndINg WITh mOdERn
SYMmetRIc ANd puBLiC key eNCryptiON algOriThMS SuCH AS aES
AnD rSa. THe deVelOPmEnt oF CRyPTOgrAPHY coNtiNUeS aND
neveR SToPs! DecRYpT the MessAGe ThAt iS hIDDeN In thE TeXt of
ThiS tAsK! thE alPhabET For tHE mEssagE cOnsiSTS of alL TWENty
SIx ENGlISh LetTErs fROM "a" tO "Z" and sIx puNCtUAtiON MARkS "
", ".", ",", "!", "?", "'"
```

which gives us the plain value:

```
WE WELCOME YOU TO THE FOURTH EDITION OF ROMANIAN CRYPTOLOGY DAYS!! WE HOPE YOU ENJOY EVERY CRYPTO MOMENT!
```

Comment: Please [edit] the contents of your link into the post so no-one has to follow the link for the crypto_text...

Comment: It is exactly the file from the second link, but just changed the quotes to be my keyboard quotes. Anyway I will put the content of the file here.

Comment: My first guess is that you are getting characters for which `ch.isupper()` is false because they are not even alphabetic. The generator which ignores certain special characters could be made more robust by **keeping** alphabetic characters rather than **ignoring** some nonalphabetic characters.

Comment: While the code you is quit elegant since it uses several single-line generators, it is also incredibly difficult to debug. You should consider breaking some of your statements apart so that you can more easily debug what your code is doing. For example, you can change your generator expressions into list comprehensions so that you can assign the result to a variable and inspect it. When you finally get it working, change them back to generators.

Comment: The text tells you your codebook are the letters a-z and six punctuation marks, i.e., `codes = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz .,!?'"`. This will fix your punctuation, because `chr(65 + 26) != ' '`. As far as the typos are concerned, I don't see a flaw. Sure, *r* is consistently translated to *s*, but your *y* is sometimes correct, sometimes *q* and sometimes *v*.

Comment: No, I don't think it's that. I already tried with `ch.isalpha()` in the first join.

Comment: I observed that y takes different values @Reti43 and I didnt come with an explanation yet why is that..

Comment: The `[`s instead of expected spaces is because the space character does not follow sequentially with the alphabetic characters in the ASCII character set.

Comment: Not the `[` is the problem, the problem is that for example y is translated different many times and also other characters

Comment: Do you get the exact same output as you do here when you used `ch.isalpha()` in the first join?

Comment: Yes @Code-Apprentice

Comment: Like I said, it's likely whoever wrote the ciphertext made some mistakes. I'm confident you selected only the letter A-Za-z. If any other characters were selected, it'd throw your whole output text off and you wouldn't get a `crypto_text` length divisible by 5. So, the only explanation is that some of the letters should have had a reverse capitalisation to get the correct result, i.e., not your fault.

Comment: Then I am back to my earlier suggestion about debugging your code.

Comment: You could also work backwards from the output. For the incorrect characters, what is the binary number which gave that result? What binary number should it be instead? Keep working back from there.

Comment: For example, if I write `THoUsANd` instead of `THoUsAnd`, I got the correct `YOU` instead of `QOU`, so maybe they wrote the wrong ciphertext (intentionally or not).

Comment: Also, what do you think it might mean `[WE^HONE[YOU[ENJOV[EIESYLCSYPTOIMOMENT^` ?. I think it is `We hope you enjoy smth crypto moment `, but what might be that smth ?

Comment: I guess the plaintext is _supposed_ to be `we welcome you to the fourth edition of romanian cryptology days!! we hope you enjoy every crypto moment!` But it looks like there are errors in the ciphertext. Eitherthat, or there's another message in those errors. ;) BTW, you do need to use the alphabet they specify: all 26 letters of the English alphabet, followed by those 6 punctuation marks, commencing with space: `" .,!?'"`

Comment: Yes @PM2Ring, you just answered my previous comment. I know that and I am using it. I will re-edit the code immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote this code without looking at yours, and I get substantially the same result. So your code is ok, the ciphertext itself must contain errors... or there's another level of message embedded in it. ;)

I've rearranged the decoding alphabet slightly to accomodate some of those errors.

```
from string import ascii_letters

src = '''\
CrYPtogRapHY iS a ScIEnce Of "seCrET wriTinG". FOr aT Least Two
THoUsAnd yeaRS ThErE haVE bEeN peOPlE WHo WAnTeD to
SEnd MESsaGes WHiCh coUlD oNLY bEeN reAd bY tHe pEOplE FOR
WhOm thEy were INtEndeD. a lOT oF different MEtHODs For
CONceaLiNG MESSAgeS weRE InvENted startINg WiTh ancient
cIPhERS lIke "skYtAle" AnD "AtbasH" AND EndINg WITh mOdERn
SYMmetRIc And puBLiC key eNCryptiON algOriThMS SuCH AS aES
AnD rSa. THe deVelOPMeNt oF CRyPTOgrAPhY coNtiNUeS aND
neveR SToPs! DecRYpT the MessAGe ThAt iS hIDDeN iN tHE TeXt of
This Task! thE alPhaBeT For thE mESsagE cOnsIsTS of alL TWENty
SIx ENGliSh letTErs fROM "a" tO "Z" and sIx puNCtUAtiON MARkS "
", ".", ",", "!", "?", "'"'''

letterset = set(ascii_letters)
#alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' + " .,!?'"
alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopysrtuvwxyz' + " .,!?'"

bits = ('01'[c.isupper()] for c in src if c in letterset)
nums = [int(''.join(u), 2) for u in zip(*[iter(bits)]*5)]

plain = ''.join([alpha[u] for u in nums])
print(plain)
```

**output**

```
we welcome you to the fourth editian of'romanian cryptology dayr!! we!hone you enjov eierylcryptoimoment!
```

Perhaps there's an explanation somewhere in here:

[4th Edition of Romanian Cryptology Days Conference](https://www.sie.ro/rcd2017/)
RCD-2017
September 18-20, 2017

Comment: I added the so said "good" version of the ciphertext, see the post above.